# passing a ConTeXt reference `(context.currentstructurereference)` to a lua function

Tags: context, lua

I'd like to pass some ConTeXt references to a Lua function. Like in the following MWE, the idea is to have tables name passed to a function via `context.currentstructurereference`. The MWE fails to compile if I uncomment the line calling context.currentstructurereference, and returns the reference if I uncomment next line (). Playing with braces did not help.

```
\startluacode 
userdata = userdata or {}
   function userdata.Test (t)
      for key,value in table.sortedhash(t)
      do
         tex.print (value)
      end
   end

Paris = {
pays = "France",
région = "Ile-de-France",
megapole = "oui"
}

\stopluacode

\starttext

\startsection[title={Paris},reference={Paris}]

\startluacode
context(context.currentstructurereference)
context.par()
userdata.Test(Paris)
-- userdata.Test(context.currentstructurereference) --does not compile
-- userdata.Test(context.currentstructurereference()) --not the expected result
\stopluacode
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

What should I do to get the same result as `userdata.Test(Paris)` calling `context.currentstructurereference`?

Comment: I don't think this will work.  Keep in mind that using `context.<whatever>` accesses TeX and communication between Lua and TeX is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get something like this to work, but there are two conceptual mistakes in your code.

First, the function `userdata.Test(...)` expects the name of a Lua table as the argument. No matter what you do, `context.currentstructurereference` will never point to a Lua table. So, the first thing that you need to do is to change the argument of the `userdata.Test(...)`. The simplest way to change it is such that it expects a string, which is the key in a table which stores the relevant data. One option is as follows:

```
\startluacode 
userdata = userdata or {}

local references = {
  ["Paris"] = {
                pays = "France",
                région = "Ile-de-France",
                megapole = "oui"
              },
}


function userdata.Test (ref)
  local tbl = references[ref]
  for key, value in table.sortedhash(tbl)
  do
     tex.print (value)
  end
end
\stopluacode
```

Now, if we can somehow pass the value of `context.currentstructurerefence` (which is a TeX macro), as a string to Lua, we are good. Your attempt of using `userdata.Test(context.currentstructurereference)` still does not work. Why?

The `context.` namespace is uses a metaprogramming trick: when you call `context.something`, it is roughly equivalent to `tex.print("\\something")`, with some fancy features:

- `context.something("arg")` is equal to `tex.print("\\something{arg}")`
- `context.something({key=value}, "arg")` is equal to `tex.print("\\something[key=value]{arg}")`

One of the fancy things which the `context` macro does is called delayed processing (which is needed when passing control back and forth between TeX and Lua). At a high-level,

- `context.something(function ... end)` is equal to `output of function`.

You can check this by running the following code:

```
\startluacode
  context(function() context("Hello") end)
\stopluacode
```

So, `context.currentstructurereference()` is a function, which effectively calls `tex.sprint("\\currentstructurereference{}")` which prints the expanded value of `\currentstructurereference` to the TeX stream. So,

```
\startluacode
  context(context.currentstructurereference)
\stopluacode
```

is roughly same as simply calling[^1] `context.currentstructurereference`. Of course, this doesn't work with the `userdata.Test` function because: (i) it expects a Lua table (or a Lua string in our modified version above); (ii) `context.something` is equal to `tex.print("\\something")` so it writes the TeX string and the value is not seen by Lua at all. What you can do, is the surprisingly simple:

```
\startluacode
   userdata.Test("\currentstructurereference")
\stopluacode
```

Note that I am using `"\currentstructurereference"` rather than `"\\currentstructureference"`. So, `\currentstructurereference` gets expanded  right away, so you will get the value of `\currentstructurereference` at the time `\startluacode` is encountered. This works in the minimal example that you had, but might fail if your actual usecase was more complicated.

[^1]: Strictly speaking, this is not true. There is a notion of a delayed call, but I'll not go into that here. See the CLD manual for details.